# Casestovars in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have to following `data.frame` in R:

```
RINPERSOONS RINPERSOON Praktijknummer AanvangWaarneem EindeWaarneem
R 1 15 20120101 20121231
R 2 16 20120101 20120612
R 2 16 20120613 20121231
R 3 17 20120307 20120906
R 3 17 20120907 20121231
```

I want to reshape this `data.frame`, so that the combination of ID-variables RINPERSOONS, RINPERSOON and Praktijknummer uniquely identifies a record in the new dataframe, and the variables AanvangWaarneem Eindewaarneem become new variables AanvangWaarneem1, EindeWaarneem1...AanvangWaarneemN, EindeWaarneemN.

In SPSS I would simply use `Casestovars`, but how do I do this in R? It looks like I need `cast` from the "reshape" package, but after `cast(df,RINPERSOONS+RINPERSOON+Praktijknummer~.......)` I am lost. And the documentation on cast is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a "time" variable before you can reshape to the "wide" format. This can be done easily with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package. After adding the ID, you can use `reshape` from base R.

```
library(splitstackshape)
reshape(getanID(mydf, 1:3), direction = "wide", 
        idvar = names(mydf)[1:3], timevar = ".id")
#    RINPERSOONS RINPERSOON Praktijknummer AanvangWaarneem.1
# 1:           R          1             15          20120101
# 2:           R          2             16          20120101
# 3:           R          3             17          20120307
#    EindeWaarneem.1 AanvangWaarneem.2 EindeWaarneem.2
# 1:        20121231                NA              NA
# 2:        20120612          20120613        20121231
# 3:        20120906          20120907        20121231
```

You can also use the "tidyr" + "dplyr" approach. Along with "splitstackshape", you could do:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  getanID(1:3) %>%
  gather(var, val, ends_with("Waarneem")) %>%
  unite(Var, var, .id) %>%
  spread(Var, val)
```

If you want to skip using "splitstackshape" but still want to use "tidyr" and "dplyr", you can try:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(RINPERSOONS, RINPERSOON, Praktijknummer) %>%
  mutate(.id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gather(var, val, ends_with("Waarneem")) %>%
  unite(Var, var, .id) %>%
  spread(Var, val)
```

Comment: @akrun, best is subjective to a large extent. Thumbs up on your answer too.

Comment: Actually, I did try on reshape first, but the getanID part didn't came right and went ahead with dcast. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2`, you can `melt` the 'wide' format to 'long', create a sequence variable with `ave`, and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(df, id.var=c('RINPERSOONS', 'RINPERSOON', 'Praktijknummer'))
dM1 <- transform(dM, indx =ave(seq_along(RINPERSOONS), 
     RINPERSOONS,RINPERSOON, Praktijknummer, FUN=seq_along))
dcast(dM1,...~variable+indx, value.var='value')
#     RINPERSOONS RINPERSOON Praktijknummer AanvangWaarneem_1 AanvangWaarneem_2
#1           R          1             15          20120101                NA
#2           R          2             16          20120101          20120613
#3           R          3             17          20120307          20120907
#  EindeWaarneem_2 EindeWaarneem_3 EindeWaarneem_4
#1        20121231              NA              NA
#2              NA        20120612        20121231
#3              NA        20120906        20121231
```